# SQL split duplicates and rename

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have a table with employee ID and UserNames. Some of the employee IDs are duplicates but the UserName is different. I need to break off the duplicates and add them back to the list with new employee IDs.

For example:

```
EMPID|UserName
1    | Josh
2    | John
2    | Kate
2    | Jorge
3    | Taylor
3    | Morgan
4    | Nathan
```

I need to switch it to:

```
1|Josh
2|John
3|Taylor
4|Nathan
5|Kate
6|Jorge
7|Morgan
```

I know the SQL to find duplicates. But to do this type of move I am at a lost.

Thank You!

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: why you are trying to find duplicates? set `EmpId` of all your users again.

Comment: Using Mircosoft SQL 2008 R2.

Comment: I have to keep the unique ones with the same EmpId.

Comment: find all duplicates, find max EmpId, set duplicates EmpId with a sequential number starts at maximum empId

Answer (score 0):

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (EMPID INT, UserName VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
(1 ,'Josh') ,(2 ,'John')  ,(2 ,'Kate'),
(2 ,'Jorge'),(3 ,'Taylor'),(3 ,'Morgan'),4 ,'Nathan')
```

### UPDATE Query

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
 SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EMPID,UserName) + (SELECT MAX(EMPID) FROM @TABLE) New_ID
 FROM @TABLE t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT EMPID , MAX(UserName) AS UserName1
                  FROM @TABLE
                  WHERE  EMPID = t.EMPID
                  GROUP BY EMPID
                  HAVING   MAX(UserName) = t.UserName)
)
UPDATE CTE 
 SET EMPID = New_ID
```

### RESULT

SELECT * FROM @Table

```
╔═══════╦══════════╗
║ EMPID ║ UserName ║
╠═══════╬══════════╣
║     1 ║ Josh     ║
║     2 ║ Kate     ║
║     3 ║ Taylor   ║
║     4 ║ Nathan   ║
║     5 ║ John     ║
║     6 ║ Jorge    ║
║     7 ║ Morgan   ║
╚═══════╩══════════╝
```